# How would you integrate a function containing a definite integral (without calculating the integral)?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Suppose you had the function $f(x)=(\int^{x}_{0} e^{-u^{2}} du)^{2}$. How would you find $f'(x)$? The integral in the function is a bit nasty, but I've been told that there is a way to find the derivative without calculating the integral. What method would be used to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Use the chain rule, the derivative of the integral itself just equals $e^{-x^2}$ itself.  So just wrap that in $x\mapsto x^2$ and use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

If we first denote the integral function of the inner function as 
$$ G(x) = \int_0^x e^{-u^2} \ du$$
Now by definition of the integral function we have
$$ G'(x) = e^{-x^2}$$
Now if we consider your function we have
$$ f(x) = (G(x))^2$$
The derivative is found with the chain rule
$$ f'(x) = 2G'(x)G(x)$$
So
$$ f'(x) = 2e^{-x^2} \int_0^x e^{-u^2} \ du$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f: x \overset{g}{\mapsto} \int_{u=0}^{x}e^{-u^{2}} =: y \overset{h}\mapsto y^{2}$; then by chain rule we have
$f'(x) = (h'\circ g)(x)\cdot g'(x) = 2\int_{u=0}^{x}e^{-u^{2}}(e^{-x^{2}}).$